# How to find array column sum using Java streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a 2D integer array:

```
int arr[][] = new int[rows][columns];
```

The nth Row sum can be found using:

```
int rSum=Arrays.stream(arr[n]).sum();
```

How can I find the pth Column sum?

```
int cSum=Arrays.stream(arr[][p]).sum();
```

The above line does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map every row on the `p`-th element:

```
int cSum = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(row -> row[p]).sum();
```

This works as follows: first we construct a stream from the `arr`. This stream will contain the *rows* of the "matrix". Then for every such `row`, we `mapToInt` it to an `int`: the `p`-th element of that row. Then we `sum(..)` the stream of `int`s together to the sum.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be Arrays.stream though

Answer (score 3):

```
    int arr[][] = new int[][] {
            {1,2},{3,4},{5,6}
    };
    int s = Arrays.stream(arr).mapToInt(a -> a[1]).sum();
    System.out.println(s); // 12
```